# How can I sell my equipment?

Tags: dark-souls-2

I just started playing *Dark Souls 2* without playing the first one.

Since I don't see any sell option in any merchant: Can I sell my old-unused-equipment for souls?
If I cannot sell it, does it have any value to be keep until later?

Comment: I don't know about Dark Souls 2, since it's not out yet, but in Dark Souls 1 and Demon's Souls you could not sell items for souls. In Dark Souls there was an NPC that would give some very few souls for giving him your items (Kingseeker Frampt), but he was not available for the whole playthrough. I reckon there is no "normal" way to sell items in Dark Souls 2 either.

Comment: Since the game is now officially out should this question be reopend?

Comment: @AdamP Generally, we don't reopen questions when the game is released. In this case, however, the question probably *shouldn't have been closed in the first place* (although it was asked prior to release), because it was in that grey area where people can already have "legitimately" obtained copies.

Comment: I only know of one merchant (Gavlan) so far where you can sell stuff too. It is however a 1 time occurrence.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There is an NPC named ***Gavlan*** that will purchase items and equipment from the player. He is the only NPC that serves this function.

He is initially found in

> No-Man's Wharf

but moves once you've spoken to him. This means that at each location until the final one, you'll only be able to sell to him once.

The second location is:

> Harvest Valley

The third and final location is:

> Doors of Pharros

Source is the Collector's Edition Guidebook, pg 428.